# top command, why such a big difference between VIRT and RES, while swap is 0?

Tags: ubuntu, memory, top

I've read some posts that says a process's `VIRT = RES + SWAP`. But look at the screenshot below, the whole system's `Swap` is `0` (`0 used`). So I expect each process's `VIRT` at least **≈** `RES`. But as you can see there's a huge difference.

Why? Do I misunderstand something?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`VIRT` is the amount of address space that the process has allocated, `RES` is the amount of memory that the process is using. Swap isn’t involved here, and the only relationship is that `RES` plus the amount of backing store used by the process (swap or something else) is less than `VIRT`.

It’s usual for processes to allocate more address space than they’ll use.